# Solvability of the equation $2a_{1}^{2} = a_{2}^{n} + a_{3}^{n} + a_{4}^{n}$ when $n \geq 5$ is prime?

Tags: reference-request, diophantine-equations

As a natural extension of the question titled
[Solvability of $a_{1}^{2} = a_{2}^{n} + a_{3}^{n} + a_{4}^{n}$ when $n \geq 5$ is prime?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269338/solvability-of-a-12-a-2n-a-3n-a-4n-when-n-geq-5-i/1269860#1269860),
I wonder if the equation
$$2a_{1}^{2} = a_{2}^{n} + a_{3}^{n} + a_{4}^{n}$$
is solvable for co-prime $a_i$ when $n \geq 5$ is prime?

The Darmon-Merel theorem asserts that $a_{1}^{2} \neq a_{2}^{n} + a_{3}^{n}$ for all $n \geq 3$ and all integers $a_{1}, a_{2}, a_{3}$ not all 
$0$, but I am not sure about the result when $2a_{1}^{2}$ is considered instead.

If there is already any known result in existence, bringing it in is more than welcome.

Comment: Sorry. Could the person who voted to close this question please explain? I do not understand your chosen reason.

Comment: Don't mind them, Chou. Some people here try to close questions at the drop of a hat. It would have been better if the ability to cast close votes  was only for very _high-rep_ users.

Comment: I did a quick search on $a^n+b^n+c^n = m z^n$ with positive and co-prime $a\leq b \leq  c \leq 100$. Since the high power $n=8$ is solvable for $m=2$, I was expecting it to be also solvable for at least $n=5$. Unfortunately, there were no solutions for $n=5,6,7$ in that limited range I used, though a higher search radius might yield results.

Comment: Consider [this little program](http://pastebin.com/zym1iBQm) for further cases.

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin: Your program found the co-prime solutions, $$39^5+75^5+128^5 =2\cdot135689^2$$ $$39^5+80^5+123^5 =2\cdot125539^2$$ $$73^5+121^5+144^5 =2\cdot212047^2$$ You should transfer these three as an answer.

Comment: Giovanni Resta has searched $a^n+b^n+c^n = 2z^2$ with $a,b,c<7000$ and $a,b,c<3000$ for $n=6,7$ respectively, and found $no$ coprime solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know why co-prime solutions are more interesting and must these be mutual co-prime or co-prime altogether, but there are few mutual co-prime  ones $a_1,a_2,a_3<1000$ (not sure all of these found due to precision trunks):
$$\begin{align}4^5+239^5+659^5=2\cdot 7907819^2\\
40^5+ 617^5+ 633^5= 2\cdot 9773625^2\\
73^5+ 121^5+ 144^5= 2\cdot 212047^2\\
96^5+ 709^5+ 877^5= 2\cdot 18681029^2\\
161^5+ 380^5+ 479^5= 2\cdot 4077240^2\\
211^5+335^5+704^5=2\cdot 9422435^2\\
224^5+387^5+541^5=2\cdot 5271996^2\\
360^5+493^5+517^5=2\cdot 6004405^2\\
369^5+640^5+881^5=2\cdot 17957625^2\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Co-primality is impt because it is easy to construct solutions without this constraint. For ex, starting with $$\frac{1^7+1^7+2^7}{2} = 65$$ multiply the whole thing with $65^7$ and you get, $$65^7+65^7+130^7 = 2\cdot 65^8 = 2\cdot 17850625^2$$ which is somehow "cheating".

Comment: @TitoPiezasIII : I'd say of "basic" solutions then, 'cause $6^5+ 6^5+6^5=2\cdot 108^2$, $10^5+ 10^5+ 30^5=2\cdot 3500^2$, $17^5+ 17^5+ 34^5=2\cdot 4913^2$ are not co-prime but rather interesting though.

Comment: Add something to your code such that $a_1\leq a_2\leq a_3$ and $a_3/a_1$ is **NOT** an integer. It is a test that most co-prime solutions will pass, though a few non-coprimes will pass as well. But it will eliminate a lot of solutions like $17^5+17^5+34^5$.